# How do I to forward example.com to www.example.com at godaddy for s3 hosted site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, forwarding

I have:

1. signed up for an AWS account
2. set up buckets for `example.com` and `www.example.com`
3. enabled website settings in properties for each domain
4. set bucket policies for both domains
5. created this cname record:
   www  >  `www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Right now when a user goes to `www.example.com`, they see the index page, and everything is working just fine. When they go to `example.com`, there is nothing but darknenss and silence because the page just doesn't load (and gives 'connection timeout' error. )

What I want is for `example.com` to forward to `www.example.com` so that no matter what the user types in the browser, they see the site that is located at `www.example.com`.

- How do I make this work?
- Can I add a record of some kind at godaddy to make `example.com` redirect to `www.example.com`?
- Do I have to get a static IP to make this work using s3? I keep reading about an elastic IP from EC2, but I am not understanding how I can set that up, or how it would work since I am not using EC2 at all for my website.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think user Go Daddy's answer was correct, but I'll write up more succinct instructions that I followed to get the forwarding to work for me. I don't know why others are suggesting wwwizer, because GoDaddy uses a 301-redirect too (but maybe it didn't used to?). By the way, this answer isn't specific to Amazon's S3 -- it simply requires you have the "www" CNAME record set correctly.

1. Login to `GoDaddy.com`.
2. Click on **My Account**.
3. Click on the **Domains** product, and click the **Launch** button next to your domain.
4. In the **Domain Information** section you should see "Forwarding: Off". Click the **Manage** link next to it.
5. A **Forwarding and Masking** dialog box should come up. Under **Forward `example.COM` to** enter `www.example.com`.
6. Click the **OK** button.

The forwarding kicked in for me within maybe half an hour.

To note, in the dialog box you can change it to forward either "http://" or "https://".  I only needed it for "http://", so I'm not sure if GoDaddy will forward both SLL and non-SSL at the same time.

Also, if you're curious, if you click on the **Advanced Options** link in the **Forwarding and Masking** dialog box, it should be defaulted to "Forward Only" and have the redirect type set to permanently forward your domain (which is what gives the 301-redirect).

Answer (score 14):

You can use wwwizer's free naked domain redirect service:

http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect

Just put 174.129.25.170 as the A record for the non-www version of your domain.

Answer (score 4):

**Update : Jul 2019**
Since the original accepted answer by Michael Krebs  in 2012, screens/ui might have changed little bit.
Please follow the screenshots below for the latest steps as of today:

[image: godaddy domain management]

Then click on add.

[image: godaddy forwarding domain]

Answer (score 3):

fragholrok,

I'm glad you were able to find a way to get your site working. Admittedly, it's a little hard to understand exactly what's going on with your domain name without more specific info, but I wanted to jump in and mention one thing.

You weren't sure if you could forward your domain to the www subdomain. It depends how you have it setup - sometimes it will work and sometimes it won't. According to your original post, the www subdomain is setup with its own CNAME (as opposed to mirroring the main A Record). Because of this, you COULD forward your domain to the www subdomain - ie, forward domain.com to www.domain.com - using GoDaddy.com's domain forwarding functionality.

If, however, the CNAME for a subdomain is set to '@', which means it directs to the main A Record, forwarding the domain to the subdomain would not work.

I just wanted to clarify for anyone else who might come across this thread.

Good luck with your site,

Alon
GoDaddy.com Social Media

Comment: Oh! I was a bit confused by the cname/a record thing so thanks for clarifying! I'm sure I'm not the only one confused about it, so I agree that this info will be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your DNS/Name Servers on GoDaddy aren't set up right.  They should have the information listed for the Nameservers somewhere where you're hosting the site.

**EDIT:** I've done some more looking around and it would Amazon doesn't provide you the Nameservers for S3. The "real solution" to this would be to set up a CName on GoDaddy. This site provides a lot of insight on doing that: http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58317

Also, this question seems to have come up before: [Using GoDaddy Domain Hosting to link to Amazon S3 Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348068/using-godaddy-domain-hosting-to-link-to-amazon-s3-website)

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this for days :( The blogger link didn't actually give any real answers in terms of what cname record to add for a naked domain, it only talks about creating a cname for www which I already I have.  As far as domain forwarding through godaddy, I don't think I can forward my domain to itself (since godaddy treats www.domain.com and domain.com as the same domain for forwarding purposes from what I can tell). The site wwwizer.com from the last link you posted worked like a charm! (don't know how I missed that post, ooops!) Anyway, THNX!!!

Answer (score 1):

I used the approach described in 
http://thechrisoshow.com/2011/06/05/how-to-host-a-static-website-on-s3/
(also with godaddy).

It boils down to deleting the A host entry, creating a CNAME entry and using godaddy's forwarding functionality.

For me it is a partial solution. It works if I type 
jaumebarcelo.info
in the url bar.

But it does not work if I click on a link pointing to
jaumebarcelo.info

or if I type
wget jaumebarcelo.info from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for the same answer.  How I have done it in the past is with an apache htaccess rewrite.  I may do it again this way.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

[Here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/226.htm) is one such page that talks about it.

If you need more help I would google htaccess and apache rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Route 53, you can create a new bucket with your naked domain name, and under 'Static Website Hosting', set it to 'Redirect all requests to another host name'.

Comment: @JustinPoehnelt how did you get it to work for https then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to be using CloudFront for https support.

Answer (score -1):

If no `A` record and `www` sub-domain is bound with subdomain it should redirect root domain to `www` sub-domain. This is how it works with many other sites.