# How do I make all pages have www in front of them?

Tags: seo, google-search, no-www

I have a website that is `http://www.example.com`.

However, Google is showing it as `example.com`.  It even has different cache's.  One for `www.example.com` and one for `example.com`.

When I type it into my address bar they come out the same, but Google has them differently. How do I fix this?

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: @VahidND how do i know?

Comment: Are you using iis, Apache or ...? And if you are using a CMS, which CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with following ways.

**1.)** You can add domain forwarding for your domain `example.com` to `www.example.com` on your domain provider. So, whenever you request to `example.com`, it will be redirected to `www.example.com`. By doing this, you won't see `example.com` on google search results. You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870638/how-do-i-to-forward-domain-com-to-www-domain-com-at-godaddy-for-s3-hosted-site) for example domain forwarding

**2.)** You can create a webmaster tools account [here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home). After that go to `Site Settings` section(On top right corener click gear icon and click `Site Settings`). You can select preferred domain here with `www` or without `www`.