# Google search showing up the Amazon S3 website link

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

This is how I set up redirection to the Amazon S3 site:
(Basically followed instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870638/how-do-i-to-forward-domain-com-to-www-domain-com-at-godaddy-for-s3-hosted-site))

- Set up a bucket called www.mysite.com and configured it for static website hosting
- In my Godaddy account, configured:
- Added a CNAME entry for 'www' to point to the publicly accessible S3 site (like mysite.in.s3-website.amazonaws.com)
- Added a forwarding rule (302 redirect) to make both mysite.com and www.mysite.com work - whenever someone types in mysite.com, it redirects (browser url bar changes) to www.mysite.com.

Coming to my actual problem - when I do a Google search, the pages are listed under the S3 site ( **mysite.in.s3-website.amazonaws.com**) - which I'd like to think of as an implementation detail.  Is there something else I should do to get google recognize and show links under mysite.com ?

Comment: Are you setting canonical tags? https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: Nope, I hadn't giving it a try, thanks for the tip.